# Vi is aliased to vim but exit with code 1

Tags: bash, vim, vi, exit-code

This is a weird return code even I have aliased `vi` by `vim`.

I really appreciate if anyone could explain me why.

Check my commands and results below.

- `which vi` returns `/usr/bin/vi`
- `which vim` returns `/usr/bin/vim`
- `ls -al /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/vim` returns

  ```
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        3 Dec 15 03:34 /usr/bin/vi -> vim
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1745984 Dec 10 18:03 /usr/bin/vim
  ```
- `cat ~/.vimrc` returns

  ```
  set nocompatible
  silent! unmap <C-E>
  ```
- `vim` then `:q` to quit immediately. Then `echo $?` returns `0`
- `vi` then `:q` to quite immediately. **But problem is here**, `echo $?` returns `1`
- And **if second line in `.vimrc`, i.e. `silent! unmap <C-E>`, is removed**, `vi`, `:q`, `echo $?` returns `0`
- `vi` then `:version` prints

  ```
  VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct  5 2016 16:04:34)
  Included patches: 1-898 Compiled by root@apple.com Normal version
  without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
  +acl             +cindent         -conceal         +digraphs        -farsi           -gettext         +libcall         +mksession       -mouse_netterm   -mzscheme        -profile         +scrollbind      +syntax          +textobjects     +visualextra     -X11
  -arabic          -clientserver    +cryptv          -dnd             +file_in_path    -hangul_input    +linebreak       +modify_fname    -mouse_sgr       +netbeans_intg   +python/dyn      +signs           +tag_binary      +title           +viminfo         -xfontset
  +autocmd         -clipboard       +cscope          -ebcdic          +find_in_path    +iconv           +lispindent      +mouse           -mouse_sysmouse  +path_extra      -python3         +smartindent     +tag_old_static  -toolbar         +vreplace        -xim
  -balloon_eval    +cmdline_compl   +cursorbind      -emacs_tags      +float           +insert_expand   +listcmds        -mouseshape      -mouse_urxvt     -perl            +quickfix        -sniff           -tag_any_white   +user_commands   +wildignore      -xsmp
  -browse          +cmdline_hist    +cursorshape     +eval            +folding         +jumplist        +localmap        -mouse_dec       +mouse_xterm     +persistent_undo +reltime         +startuptime     -tcl             +vertsplit       +wildmenu        -xterm_clipboard
  +builtin_terms   +cmdline_info    +dialog_con      +ex_extra        -footer          -keymap          -lua             -mouse_gpm       +multi_byte      +postscript      -rightleft       +statusline      +terminfo        +virtualedit     +windows         -xterm_save
  +byte_offset     +comments        +diff            +extra_search    +fork()          -langmap         +menu            -mouse_jsbterm   +multi_lang      +printer         +ruby/dyn        -sun_workshop    +termresponse    +visual          +writebackup     -xpm    system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
       user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"  2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
        user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"   fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim" Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    
  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv
  ```
- I had tried `iTerm`, `Terminal`, changed shell to `bash`, `zsh`, `fish`. Remove first line, `set nocompatible`, in `.vimrc`. But they all returned this result.

If you need more config in my PC, please give a comment, I will provide it.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Because I opened new shell based on the current shell, via command like `zsh`, `bash`. It ignored my `.zshrc`/`.bash_profile`.

Thus, `$PATH` does not include `/usr/local/bin`. Then, instead of using homebrew `vim` 8.0 version. `which vim` pointed to default MacOS `/usr/bin/vim` version.

After trying opening open new shell by `command-T` and ensure that `which vim` returns `/usr/local/bin/vim`, i.e. homebrew's version.
`vi`, `:q`, `echo $?` echoed expected result `0`.

This solved my problem of exit code 1 after exiting `vi`, this affected `git commit` command ..etc. But I still do not understand why default MacOS version of `vi` makes this unexpected behaviour

Comment: Copy paste the exact error code seen

Comment: there is no error. The shell was clean after `vi` got exited. I manually check last command's exit code by `echo $?` and got the result

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/why-would-vim-return-non-zero-exit-code-if-i-exit-immediately-after-opening

Comment: Oh. I forgot the `~/.vim` folder. There are lots of plugin there. Editing only `~/.vimrc` is not enough

Comment: btw, thanks for providing the link. But it is still ambiguous  why removing `silent! unmap <C-E>` make thing run as expected

Comment: Same thing happening on my system.

Comment: same here. it happens on mac, but not ubuntu. most likely something about mac vim's compile options.

Comment: The error is because you're unmapping `<c-e>` but it's not mapped. Try removing the `!` from `silent!` and you'll see the error on startup. But as to why it only happens with `/usr/bin/vi`, I can reproduce that, but have no explanation.

Comment: @DanLowe: what does your `/usr/bin/vi` point to? In my case, `/usr/bin/vi` just links to `/usr/bin/vim`. And `:version` shows that it is `viM` not `vi`. My question is why `:version` shows that it is `VIM` but there is still error

Comment: @tranvansang I don't specifically know why they act different in _this_ case, but `vi` vs. `vim`, even a symlink, does matter. Programs can detect the name they were called with, and adjust their behavior. I know Vim does that in various ways, and it's probably a factor here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set to '*nocompatible*' to Vim because this is the default setting.

I remove this feature in my MacOS and works fine and with exit status 0, writing or not writing files.

Note: is MacOS 'vi' is a link to 'Vim' (and 'awk' is actually 'gawk')

Conclusion: you may use

```
silent! unmap <C-E>
```

in your *.vimrc* file and vim  may not exit with error.

Comment: That bothered me for so long when committing, but not enough to invest time to look at why it was happening. :+1: for a neat fix