# Why does vim, run as the alias "vi", return a non-zero exit code when any error happened?

Tags: vim

On my system (Mac OS X), `vi` is aliased to `vim`. However, when run as `vi`, the behavior of its exit code is different: it will return a non-zero exit code when any error happened during the session, as can be seen by the following test:

- In a terminal, open any file with vim.
- Do some editing.
- Try to exit using `:q`. This should result in an error (No write since last change).
- Exit anyway using `:q!` or `:wq`.
- Type `echo $?` in the terminal.

The return code will be 0 if I used `vim` in the first step to open vim, but will be 1 if I used `vi`.

This problem is probably the root cause of [Vi is aliased to vim but exit with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719802/vi-is-aliased-to-vim-but-exit-with-code-1).

Comment: You might want to glance here also - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/why-would-vim-return-non-zero-exit-code-if-i-exit-immediately-after-opening

Comment: It's important to note that this doesn't work when vi is a shell alias but rather when it is a symlink to the vim executable. This is necessary so that vim can inspect argv[0] to see if it is or ends with "vi". A shell alias would not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found the following remark in vim help, section `|posix-compliance|`:

```
In 2005 the POSIX test suite was run to check the compatibility of Vim. ...
...
- vi test 310 fails; exit code non-zero when any error occurred?
```

This leads me to [the following section of the POSIX specification of vi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html#tag_20_152_14).

> ### EXIT STATUS
>
> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
> 0
>
> > Successful completion.
>
> >0
>
> > An error occurred.

Obviously, many utilities have such an exit status specification, and it is usually pretty reasonable. Not in the case of `vi`, though: as an interactive editor, it is entirely possible that some command results in an error ("An error occurred"), yet the whole editor exits normally ("Successful completion"). Therefore the specification itself is ambiguous and/or contradictory, depending on your viewpoint.

Apparently, the folks writing the POSIX test suite decided that the definition of "Successful completion" should be strict: if any error occurred, it is not a successful completion. Hence `vim` failing that test.

Of course, it is not hard to modify the code of vim to comply with that interpretation of the specification if it is called as `vi`. Since the latest version of vim seems to not exhibit this behavior, I guess the Mac OS X people may have introduced this patch themselves in order to pass the POSIX test. Any difficulty in using utilities like `git commit` is probably the least of their concern.

Comment: I am confused by this answer... specifically "since the latest version of vim seems to not exhibit this behavior" ... by "this behavior" are you referring to exiting with non-zero exit code if any error occurred?  I think I've got the most recent version of vim, and it IS exiting with nonzero code if I do ANYTHING wrong.

Comment: Hmm... Which version of vim are you using? Because that is exactly what I mean --- my vim on Linux doesn't give nonzero exit code for small errors like that.

Comment: Version 8.0.1365.

Comment: I tested on 8.0.1453. I feel that the issue is probably orthogonal to the version numbers, though. How did you test this? Is it the same procedure as in my original question?